# How to get/post/delete/put information with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I trying to do a DELETE, PUT, GET and POST a request with ajax and jquery.

The method POST works well by creating a new record, but I cannot make it work the other methods (PUT, DELETE and GET).

This is the code (it works fine, it creates the new record but it doesn't reach the "success" event):

```
var jsonExample = {"advertisement":{"title":"test"}};

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://example.com/advertisements.json",
            data:jsonExample,
            success: function(response){
                    alert("test");
            }
});
```

When I change the type "POST" to "DELETE" or "PUT" I have the follow error:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

And when I change it to "GET" it throws the following message:

> 200 OK

But it don't any other responses. It should be something like this:

```
{"advertisement":{"created_at":"2012-04-17T13:20:17Z","from_age":null,"neighbourhood_id":null,"title":null,"date_to":null,"days":null,"promotion_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-17T13:20:17Z","date_from":null,"gender":null,"id":3,"display":null,"desc":null,"budget":null,"image":null,"to_age":null,"department_id":null,"town_id":null}}
```

The

Please note: my app is getting this info from a remote server, but I don't know if that has something to do with this problem. Because I've run it in Google Chrome and I've received the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** message on the browser's console.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your server configured to accept post, delete, put requests?

Comment: Depends. What tech are you using on the server side?

Comment: I'm no rails expert, but it seems you'll have define `def create`, `def destroy` and `def update` methods in the resource's controller. Look for section 2.2 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hi, I've got those methods defined, and moreoever, I've tested them locally. The problem is when I try to use methods DELETE and PUT from another domain.

Comment: For the DELETE request, try adding the data to the querystring (like `http://example.com/s?a=b&c=d`) instead of passing it to the data parameter... Let me know what happens

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make cross-domain AJAX requests using jQuery for security reasons. You may however be able to use `jsonp` providing that the URL you are requesting the data from is set up to handle `jsonp` requests.

This article should help you out alot more than I'm able to: http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll take a look at that link tomorrow, and if it works I'll mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this worked for getting and posting content, but I also need to know how to use the methods PUT and DELETE. How can I do that? Thanks.