# Problems with PUT jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with PUT in Ajax.

If I use fiddler and execute a PUT to the URL: http://domain.com:58226/api/Person/1 , with Request body: {"firstName":"Stan","lastName":"Dard"}, it works.

But when I use ajax to do the same, it doesn't work:

```
 $.ajax({
 data: '{"firstName":"Stan","lastName":"Dard"}',       //{action:'x',params:  ['a','b','c']}
 url: 'http://domain.com:58226/api/Person/'+id,
 type: 'PUT',
success: function(result) {

alert("Uppdaterad!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ajax `PUT` might not be supported by some browsers.

Comment: i have tried, firefox and chrome. The values of the firstName and lastName becomes Null. But it works in fiddler.

I jave even tried to JSONstringify the things i send in data:

Comment: when you say "doesn't" work what did you expect and what did you get instead? E.g. what error message did you get?

Comment: `i have tried, firefox and chrome. The values of the firstName and lastName becomes Null. But it works in fiddler.` fiddler is not a browser.

Comment: Fiddler says OK: but converts it to: firstName=Stab&lastName=Dard so i think the data: is the wrong thing to use to send an object. Ideas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data needs to be a String. Objects are converted to querystrings which is what you are seeing here.

You can use the `JSON.stringify(obj)` method to convert your Object to a String.

Comment: i wrote that i had tried to Stringifyit. And it was a part of the solutions. I needed to send contentType: 'text/json' and stringify it. Now it works! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

according to the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), not all browsers support it.

[image: sds]

> *But it works in fiddler.*

Fiddler is not a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this StackOverflow post:

[How to get/post/delete/put information with jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197944/how-to-get-post-delete-put-information-with-jquery-and-ajax)

"You cannot make cross-domain AJAX requests using jQuery for security reasons."

Comment: Im not doing cross-domain ajax requests. It is the same domain

Comment: In that case, have you tried setting the dataType to "json" and contentType to "application/json; charset=utf-8"? See http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to JSON.stringify the object and change contentType: text/json.